# Form submit Bootstrap Dropdown data

Tags: php, html

I have the following code, I am trying to make it so that the selected field displays on a php page when I return that hit the submit button, I'm doing this below.

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
<select class="form-control" id="inputState" style="width: 100%">
    <option selected>
        Choose...
    </option>
    <option name="account" value="1">
        Minecraft Account
    </option>
    <option name="cape" value="2">
        Minecraft Cape
    </option>
</select>
</div>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

this is my php echo code, but it does not work

```
<?php echo $_POST["account"]; ?>
<?php echo $_POST["cape"]; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set name to your select control

```
<select name="inputState" class="form-control"
```

Then you can get the "value" of selected item

```
<?php echo $_POST["inputState"]; ?>
```